# how to match the two load statements in pig

Tags: apache-pig, surrogate-key

I have two load statements `A` and `B`.
In each one I have a surrogate key.  I want to match the surrogate key columns if both keys will match the stored data.

I tried the following code.

```
A = LOAD 'a/data/' using PigStorage('\t') as (SourceWebSite:chararray,PropertyID:chararray,ListedOn:chararray,ContactName:chararray,TotalViews:int,Price:chararray);
B = LOAD 'b/data/' using PigStorage('\t') as (SourceWebsite:chararray,PropertyType:chararray,IPLSNO:int,Locality:chararray,City:chararray,Price:chararray);
C = COGROUP A BY Price, B BY Price;
D = FOREACH C GENERATE FLATTEN((IsEmpty(A) ? null : A)), FLATTEN((IsEmpty(B) ? null : B));
```

The above command prints all the data.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right you would like to have dose data where both A and B has any data for the given price, am I right?
Than you may have to use filter:

```
D = FILTER C BY (NOT IsEmpty(A) AND NOT IsEmpty(B));
```

The D will contain those data rows where both A and B has value for the price used to group.

Comment: Than of course flatten D: E = FOREACH D GENERATE FLATTEN(A), FLATTEN(B);